# Problems with collecting messages

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When I tested this it worked fine, but the bot always sent `"no one said uwu :("`

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '$uwu') {
    message.channel.send('say uwu! - i will count how many people say uwu in 30 seconds')
      .then(() => {
        message.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content === 'uwu', {
            max: 100000000,
            time: 5000,
            errors: ['time'],
          })
          .then((collected) => {
            message.channel.send(`${collected.first.size} people said uwu`);
          })
          .catch(() => {
            message.channel.send('no one said uwu :(');
          });
      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a time limit, the messages after that time limit always create an exception. But in catch you check as follows:

```
.catch((collected) => {
    if (collected.size === 0) {
        message.channel.send('no one said uwu :(');
    }
});
```

Comment: In other words, since the maximum amount of messages (`max` option) isn't reached in the specified amount of time (`time` option), an exception is thrown which triggers your `catch()` method. The code above will work as originally intended.

Comment: using the code you gave me, the bot didnt say anything after "say uwu"

Comment: I'm not sure about type of size. If it's string instead of number, it might be the issue. Maybe you could log in catch and then for better understanding the issue.

Comment: @versity Use `collected.size` in your message. `collected.first` is not a valid property; `collected.first()` is the proper method but would only return the first value which doesn't have a size.

Answer (score 0):

the code that solved my problem was,

```
    if (message.content === '$uwu') {
      message.channel.send('say uwu! - i will count how many people say uwu in 30 seconds')
        .then(() => {
          message.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content === 'uwu', {
              max: 100000000,
              time: 30000,
              errors: ['time'],
            })
            .then((collected) => {
                if (collected.size > 0  ) {
                    message.channel.send('no one said uwu :(');
              message.channel.send(`${collected.first.size} people said uwu`);
                }
            })
            .catch((collected) => {
                if (collected.size > 0) {
                    if (collected.size === 1) {
                    message.channel.send(`${collected.size} person said uwu!`);
                    }
                    else if (collected.size > 1) {
                        message.channel.send(`${collected.size} people said uwu!`);


                    }
                }
                else if (collected.size === 0) {
                    message.channel.send('no one said uwu :(')


                }
            });
        });
    }
  });
```